# Structuring an application with it's API

Tags: ssl, web-applications, architecture

I am currently developing a web application to allow customers to place orders.

The way I have choosed to handle the application structure is to split the app in two sub-applications:

- 1 backend application (the API) that serves only json content
- 1 front end application (AngularJS in my case) that takes an API url as configuration and serves user content

Now on the server, what I have done for testing, is creating 2 virtual hosts:

- app.com
- api.app.com

and linked the API to the frontend app.

The problem is that everything will be served over ***https*** and, in the current setup, I will need to buy either 2 SSL certificates, or 1 wildcard certificate.

The second solution would be to create a subdirectory on the frontend app (let's say **/api**) and copy the backend app into it. The advantage would be to get only one single SSL certificate and have everything on the same directory; the /api would be an .htaccess redirect to the backend api.

I think that the "cleanest" solution would be to split the two apps completely and get a wildcard SSL certificate for both, but I'd like to hear if someone have some experience whether one solution is better than another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of combining is that you will get to avoid [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).  CORS isn't that bad, but it's another complication.  That being said, if you want to expose this to the outside world (allow other web pages to use it), you might want to go through that process anyway.

If you aren't looking to actually expose your API to third-parties, but just keep your layers separate, than I would either look at combining, or even proxying.  I've used this architecture to put my services completely behind the firewall, and use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) or the like to serve my API through my web server.  This is useful as it limits the exposure of your API, and solves CORS issues in one go.

If you really want to use SSL between your web server and your API server, you can do a self-generated client certificate between you web-server and your API server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had the same thoughts as you, but didn't think of the proxy, can you explain me a little bit more about this technique ?

Comment: I use mod_proxy, and have entries like this:    <Location /alertService>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://api.mycompany.com/alertservice nocanon timeout=999 connectiontimeout=999
</Location>  This allows the primary web server to proxy the api, on a given path, in this case/alertservice.  It can then be served up over SSL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally chose to use the proxy way, having only one front-end app access with /api redirecting to another virtualhost on a exotic port